# How to get path where cmd is open in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, windows-10

I run Python file from cmd and I need a path where I opened cmd

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\> D:\DEV\test.py
```

I need C:\Users\test\Desktop\ path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but, to get the current working dir for the one containing your script you can use:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You can find more information in the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

Comment: @DavidS: Glad it worked! Feel free to accept the answer :)